# [international]: Synonyms around the world

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Can we synonymize [international](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/international) to [internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internationalization)?

The former has 99 questions to the latter's almost 7000. I can't imagine a question where the latter would be inappropriate, and a quick glance of the questions seems to bear that out.

Comment: From a quick glance it looks more like `international` is being used for phone numbers/addresses and postal codes/keyboard layouts - that's distinctly different than `internationalization`

Comment: Then I think it's better to burn [tag:international], since it looks like a meta tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through all the questions in [international](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/international) and they all ended up being in two categories:

- Questions about [internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internationalization), which I retagged.
- Meta tag usage, which I burned.

The tag is now empty.